# How to generate timstamp for a day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a value under timeseries pandas dataframe. However, this frame does not contain the datetime column. The data is about 1440 rows, match with 1440 minutes for a day. So, I would like to generate the minutes timestamp column for this frame, how to do that?

Desired result is under the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Before

```
        value
0       210.38
1       210.50
2       210.51
3       210.40
4       210.41
```

After

```
            datetime       value
0   2019-09-18 23:55:00    210.38
1   2019-09-18 23:56:00    210.50
2   2019-09-18 23:57:00    210.51
3   2019-09-18 23:58:00    210.40
4   2019-09-18 23:59:00    210.41
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for first column with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'datetime', pd.date_range('2019-09-18 23:55:00', periods=len(df), freq='T'))
print (df)
             datetime   value
0 2019-09-18 23:55:00  210.38
1 2019-09-18 23:56:00  210.50
2 2019-09-18 23:57:00  210.51
3 2019-09-18 23:58:00  210.40
4 2019-09-18 23:59:00  210.41
```

If want generate datetimes dynamically:

```
df.insert(0,'datetime',pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.now().floor('T'), periods=len(df),freq='T'))
print (df)
             datetime   value
0 2020-01-10 10:36:00  210.38
1 2020-01-10 10:37:00  210.50
2 2020-01-10 10:38:00  210.51
3 2020-01-10 10:39:00  210.40
4 2020-01-10 10:40:00  210.41
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
from datetime import datetime
df=pd.DataFrame({'value': [ 210.38, 210.50, 210.51, 210.40, 210.41]})
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start=datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0), periods=len(df), freq='T')
```

O/P:

```
    value                date
0  210.38 2020-01-10 15:08:32
1  210.50 2020-01-10 15:09:32
2  210.51 2020-01-10 15:10:32
3  210.40 2020-01-10 15:11:32
4  210.41 2020-01-10 15:12:32
```